# Iterations of Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition for a Simple Linear Programming problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

This arises from an engineering problem I am working on. Let $\mathbf{c}_i,\mathbf{a}_i,\mathbf{b}_i\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a given set (collection) of vectors where $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Define the polyhedrons (indexed over $i$)
$$
\mathcal{Q}_i\,=\,\{\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^d ~\lvert~ \mathbf{b}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i\leq 0,~\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}_i-1\leq 0,~\mathbf{x}_i\geq 0 \}
$$
where $\mathbf{e}$ is the all-ones vector of appropriate dimension. Now, consider the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}_i} ~&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{c}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i ~\\
~~&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i~\leq~0 \\
~~&\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathcal{Q}_i~,~~\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}
\end{align}
You can see that this can be converted to the standard input form for the Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition (DWD). However, I am curious to know given the even more specialized structure of this problem, can we specialize the iterations of the DWD?

Comment: Can you say anything more about $c$, $a$, and $b$?  Also, do you mean instead that $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Corrected the dimensionality. $\mathbf{c} _i$ are element wise positive. Can't assume anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specialize Dantzig-Wolfe by solving the subproblems (one per $i$) with an oracle other than LP.  If the constraint $\mathbf{b}_i^\top \mathbf{x}_i \le 0$ weren't there, you could enumerate the resulting $d+1$ extreme points implied by $\mathbf{e}_i^\top \mathbf{x}_i \le 1$.  You can also solve the subproblems in parallel, but I think it will be tough to beat just solving the original problem with a traditional LP algorithm like dual simplex or interior point.  Dantzig-Wolfe is generally much more useful for MILP than for LP.

Comment: Assume that the problem is easily solvable without the coupling constraint. Then, is there a easy way out?

Comment: Without the coupling constraint, the problem decomposes into $n$ disjoint $2$-constraint LPs, which should be easy even without a specialized solver. It is unclear whether it is easy enough to overcome the fact that you have to do this many times in the course of DWD. How big are $n$ and $d$? How long does it take to solve the original problem directly with an LP solver?